# div shifts without border

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove border but I can't. border: none  ,  border-style:none; border-width:0px or no definition for border. I tried all of those for the header but whenever I try, the div shifts.

[image: border:none]

And this is how it looks like with a border(any style)

[image]

And these are rest of css codes and html codes of the 2. situation.
CSS:

```
body{
top:0px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#F3F3F3;
margin:0px;
}

div#baslik{
top:0px;
width:800px;
height:230px;
border-style:solid;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-image:url('/gorsel/baslik.jpg');
}

div#siteler{
text-align:right;
height:55px;
width:800px;
padding-bottom:5px;
bottom:0px;
margin-top:195px;
padding-right:30px;
}

a:visited,a:link.siteler{
padding-right:10px;
padding-left:10px;
}

img:hover.siteler{
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #FFF;
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #FFF;
}

img.siteler{
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BAŞLIK</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='tema.css'>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/HTML; charset=utf-8' />
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='/gorsel/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id='baslik'>
        <div id='siteler'>
            <a class='siteler' href=#><img class='siteler' src='/gorsel/facebook.jpg'></a>
            <a class='siteler' href=#><img class='siteler' src='/gorsel/rss.jpg'></a>
            <a class='siteler' href=#><img class='siteler' src='/gorsel/twitter.jpg'></a>
            <a class='siteler' href=#><img class='siteler' src='/gorsel/planetminecraft.jpg'></a>
            <a class='siteler' href=#><img class='siteler' src='/gorsel/youtube.jpg'></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe `border:0`?  I'll look into it more

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with the given HTML and CSS. Are you running any scripts? Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jCda/ (just add border:none somewhere and you'll see)

Comment: nope, it didn't work.

Comment: no scripts, no php, no asp, nothing. Only html and css

Comment: Well look at my link and try `border:none;` it doesn't shift. I am also using Chrome.

Comment: I tried on both Chrome and Firefox, both failed. It seems that problem is about me but not the browsers or the code.

Comment: Try uploading it to a page on your website if you can, sometimes there are discrepancies between local and hosted files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [margin collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins). When `#baslik` has top border or top padding, it contains the top margin of `#siteler` inside. When no border or padding separates their margins, they are merged into one margin that shifts them both.

To prevent it, you can remove `margin-top:195px;` from `#siteler` and replace `height:230px;` with `height:35px; padding-top: 195px` for `#baslik`.